# How can I display the hierarchy of my custom objects in a Visualforce page using a datatable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, datatable, hierarchy

In advance of posting this question, I have attempted to use maps and wrapper classes. I've already made several attempts for the past two months using the suggestions on this forum and the SF developer forum to create custom hierarchy extension controllers, but nothing has worked perfectly.

What I'm trying to do is display long form responses on a VF page using a data table using an integration from FormAssembly, which is a survey website.

My objects and relationships are:

- `Form__c` (Master)
- `Section__c` (Child)
- `Question__c` (Grandchild)
- `Response__c` (Great-grandchild)

Additionally not every `Question__c` has a `Question_Batch__c`, but every `Question_Batch__c` looks up to a `Question__c` and `Section__c`/.

An example of a `Question_Batch__c` is a "Mailing Address," which looks up to the `Section__c`, "Contact Information," which looks up to the `Question__c`s, "Street Address," "City," "State," and "Country."

The apex code extension I have written currently is:

```
    public ListFormObjects(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    
    }
    
    public List<Section__c> getSections(){
        return [SELECT Name,
                Question__r.Question_Text__c
                FROM Section__c
               WHERE Form__c = :Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
    
 public List<Response__c> getResults() {
        return [SELECT Name,
                       Response__c,
                       Question__r.Id,
                       Question__c,
                       Question__r.Section__c,
                       Question__r.Question_Text__c,
                       Question__r.Question_Batch__c,
                       Question__r.Question_Batch__r.Name,
                       Question__r.Section__r.Name,
                       Question__r.Section__r.Form__c,
                       Question__r.Section__r.Form__r.Name
                FROM Response__c
               WHERE Question__r.Section__r.Form__c = 
                      :Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

 }
    }
```

The Visualforce I have written currently is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Form__c" lightningStyleSheets="true" extensions="ListFormObjects">
<style> .title{padding: 10px;margin: 10px;} </style>
  <h1 class="title">Form Viewer</h1>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Submission Details">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Form__c}" var="ft">
            <apex:column headerValue="Form" width="200px" >
            Reporting Month: {!ft.Reporting_Month__c} <br/>
            Name: {!ft.Name}<br/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Dates" width="200px">
            <apex:outputText value="Submitted Date: {0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}"
            style="{!IF(ft.Submitted_Date__c > ft.Due_Date__c, 'color: #EE4034; font-weight:600;', '')}">
                <apex:param value="{!ft.Submitted_Date__c}" /> 
                </apex:outputText>  <br/>
            <apex:outputText value="Due Date: {0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
                <apex:param value="{!ft.Due_Date__c}" /> 
                </apex:outputText><br/>
            </apex:column>    
       </apex:pageBlockTable>       
       </apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Submitter Details">

    <apex:detail subject="{!Form__c.Contact__c}" relatedList="false" title="true">
        <style type="text/css">
        input.btn[name="del"] {
            display: none;
        }
        input.btn[name="clone"] {
            display: none;
        }
        input.btn[name="edit"] {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
    </apex:detail>
    </apex:pageblocksection>
       
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageblocksection title="Form Details" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Sections}" var="s">
        <apex:column value="{!s.Name}"/>
        <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="2">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Results}" var="r" rendered="true">
                <apex:column value="{!r.Question__r.Question_Text__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!r.Response__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!r.Question__r.Section__r.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!r.Question__r.Question_Batch__r.Name}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:column>
       </apex:pageBlocktable>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is an example of how the data table renders:
[image: Data Table]

This is an example of the full Visualforce page:
[image: Full Visualforce Page]

My goal is to get the Sections to be ordered 1-3 and then to show the Question Batches below the Sections. Then below that I'd like to see the corresponding Questions and Responses.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, are you aware of FormAssembly's [app for SF](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ac6EAA)? And while we're at it, SF has [native Survey functionality](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/get-started-with-salesforce-surveys)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but have you tried custom controllers? You should be able to make the page behave more or less however you like with custom controllers. This book has helped me a lot in the past - https://www.packtpub.com/product/visualforce-development-cookbook/9781782170808. You can look at the code errata to give you some ideas.

Also, is there a reason you are using Visualforce instead of LWC?

Comment: @identigral Thanks for your response. I'm aware of FA's app for SF and we have it implemented it in our org. However (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong), FA was designed for data gathering and mapping to existing objects (including custom objects), not survey or form creation, which is why I created my own form objects. On top of that as a nonprofit, we don't have SF community licenses which are required of the native Survey functionality. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks, @AndyHitchings actually there is no reason I'm using VF over LWC, aside from not having experience with LWC. Do you think I should redirect my efforts there instead?

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for editing.

Comment: Salesforce's Survey product is certainly available in/via Experience Cloud - see [this implementation guide (PDF download)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/surveys.pdf). It's not directly related to your Exp Cloud license because Surveys is an additional paid product, you pay based on usage. There's also a very limited but free [SurveyForce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003I2gDEAS) app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the pricing structure for SF's Survey product @identigral, as a non-profit, already using a survey software (meaning FormAssembly) we need to minimize the amount of products that we are purchasing and repurpose them for multiple uses if necessary. In this case it was determined before I started this project that we would utilize FA, so I'm still looking for a solution to do so. Plus this "form viewer" page is the last piece in an already working puzzle.